# Vue3 : How to override function with the composition API?

Tags: vue.js, overriding, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Let's say we have a compasable function like below:

```js
// composable/useShareComp.ts
export function useShareComp() {
  const toto = "hey";
  const tata = ref(0);

  function utilMethod() {
    console.log("Util Méthod !!");
  }
  function mainMethod() {
    console.log("Main Méthod !!");
    console.log("should call the overriden or fallback to this utilMethod");
    utilMethod()
  }
  return { toto, tata,  utilMethod,  mainMethod };
};
```

Now, I have 2 components that will use the composable method. (I use the new 3.2 version)

```js
// components/SharComp.vue

<template>
  <h1>share comp</h1>
  <p>{{toto}}</p>
  <p>{{tata}}</p>
  <button @click="mainMethod">call main method</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { useShareComp } from "@/composable/useShareComp";

const { toto, tata, mainMethod } = useShareComp();
</script>
```

So above if the `mainMethod` is called it will simply called the `utilMethod` and thus log "Util Méthod !!"

But now I want in another component to override the `utilMethod` like in the code below

```js
// components/MyNewComp.vue

<template>
  <h1>MY NEW COMP</h1>
  <p>{{toto}}</p>
  <p>{{tata}}</p>
  <button @click="mainMethod">call main method</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">

import { useShareComp } from "@/composable/useShareComp";

const { toto, tata, mainMethod } = useShareComp();

function utilMethod() { // it will not override the utilMethod
  console.log("Util Method but in the MyNewComp!");
}
</script
```

In the MyNewComp component, I want `utilMethod` to be overridden and thus when `mainMethod` is called, it should log the new  console.log("Util Method but in the MyNewComp!");
from the overridden utilMethod.
But I don't have any idea of how to do that as we could easily do with some natives classes (and/or with the vue-class-components library)

Comment: why not use computed in the place of utilMethod ?

Comment: What do you mean? can you please exemplify it?

Comment: It is really sad vue3 "deprecated" the class api. Overriding a function was/is a piece of cake with it. I dont even know why they should do that. Maybe to few OOP devs in the vue team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass the `utilMethod` as callback with default logic and you could override it :

```
// composable/useShareComp.ts
function defaultUtilMethod() {
    console.log("Util Méthod !!");
  }
export function useShareComp(utilMethod=defaultUtilMethod) {
  const toto = "hey";
  const tata = ref(0);

  
  function mainMethod() {
    console.log("Main Méthod !!");
    console.log("should call the overriden or fallback to this utilMethod");
    utilMethod()
  }
  return { toto, tata,  utilMethod,  mainMethod };
};
```

and :

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { useShareComp } from "@/composable/useShareComp";
function utilMethod() {
  console.log("Util Method but in the MyNewComp!");
}
const { toto, tata, mainMethod } = useShareComp(utilMethod);


</script
```

**example using pure js**

```js
function a() {
  console.log("aaaaa")
}

function b(f = a) {
  console.log('bbbbbb')
  f();
}

function c() {
  console.log("cccc")
}
console.log('------default callback--------')
b(); //prints bbbbbb aaaaa
console.log('------overriding the callback--------')
b(c); //prints bbbbbb cccc
```

Comment: I thought about that but would like a better idiomatic way to do that like the `override`  keyword. But anyway, it is still a go way to achieve that.

Comment: This is not possible in javascript, you could also pass the callback as param in `mainMethod` function

Comment: Yes but vue js could implement an idiomatic way to do that.

Comment: a way like what?

Comment: Like we can do natively with classes. Or with vue mixins.